# ng-repeat for object (hash) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The normal way of learning ng-repeat is as follows

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.attribute}}</li>
```

and you would have a controller such as

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.items = [
          { name : kitten, attribute : value },
          { name : puppy, attribute : value }
     ];
});
```

This is good and all, but it gets clunky when I get deeper into my app and have to reference items by their array index.  A function that modify's kitten's attribute will go:

```
$scope.items[0].attribute = value;
```

I would much rather have:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.items = {
          'kitten' : {attribute : value },
          'puppy' : { attribute : value }
     };
});
```

so that I can

```
$scope.items.kitten.attribute = NEW
-or-
$scope.items["kitten"].attribute = NEW
(are these equivalent??  I think so)
```

But then how would I loop through them?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.attribute}}</li>
```

does not work.

Comment: In addition to tymeJV's answer, please take the habit always to check [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat). All the answers are there.

Comment: The documentation is cryptic.  Answers here are always helpful.  Im new to Angular.  Please take back your DV.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax:

```
ng-repeat="(k, v) in o"
```

`k` is the key of the property iterated over, `v` is the value, and `o` is the object being iterated.

Comment: I knew you'd answer this one.

Comment: @dckuehn - Just got back from lunch :D

Comment: so would it be (name, attribute) in o?  What if I had different attributes and didn't want to sepcify each one specifically (name, attr1, attr2, ...) in o

Comment: if you want the cat name then it will be 
<li ng-repeat="(key, values) in items">{{key}}</li>

if you want those other attribute value it will just simpley be
<li ng-repeat="(key, values) in items">{{values.attribute}}</li>

if you have nested attribution u will get values.attribute.xxx.yyy